How to download webpage as JSON with Playwright?
I'm trying to pull almost all the data from a webpage using Playwright and I want to save it as a JSON. I am able to log in and get to the webpage with the data I want, but I'm not sure how to download that page as a JSON. Specifically, I want the contents of <div id="request-data" class="col-lg-12">, but I would settle for the whole page.
Here is the general setup of my code:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with sync_playwright() as p:
    # Open Browser
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=500)

    # Open Webpage
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://google.com/")

    # To Do: Save Webpage Contents as JSON
    

I have everything in one python file. In my code, I go to a different site to do some other stuff before the JSON download, but my question stands even for this small example: Once I am on a webpage, how can I use playwright to download the page as a JSON?
Sorry for the very simple question but all of the documentation I have found on this topic is in JS rather than Python, and I can't even tell if it addresses my question or not, or it's about reading from a JSON rather than saving one.

What output do you expect exactly? There is no single way to convert a whole webpage to JSON, unless you're referring to converting all HTML elements into a JSON tree following some custom structure (I'm not sure why you'd want that, though). The way to scrape a page is to figure out what data you want, what output structure you want, query the elements and extract the text, then put it into the desired output structure. You might want to clarify your use case at a high level.

I don't see document.querySelector("#request-data") anywhere on the page on google.com.
